# Converting a 'string number' to a number

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a library and trying to send a string into the function and return it as a Number, while creating a conditional to determine if the string sent into the function is a number before I do the conversion.

```
var strNum = function(val){
    if (!isNan(val)){
        console.log('This is a string that can be converted')
        parseInt(val)
        return val
    }else{
        console.log ('This sting is not a "number"');
    }
};
```

This is what I have but when debugging it I get an error of 
*"ReferenceError: isNan is not defined if (val = !isNan(val)){"* 
and I'm not sure why its isn't working!

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's `isNaN()` (note the second upper-case N), not `isNan()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's `isNaN` not `isNan`.

There is no method named `isNan` in javascript that's why its throwing reference error.